# How do I convert an array or a list into a hashref?

Tags: arrays, perl, dictionary, hashref, arrayref

I have a list like this:

```
my $myV3VersionOfData = ["ZG","ZB","CXLDN",...];
```

and I want to convert it into a dictionary like this:

```
my $entries = {
'ZG' => {
'value' => 'ZG'
},
'ZB' => {
'value' => 'ZB'
},
'CXLDN' => {
'value' => 'CXLDN'
},
...
};
```

I tried this so far, but it doesn't work and gives me an error:

> Can't use string ("ZG") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at..

I understand this is occurring since I'm trying to assign the key value from the list, but how do I convert this list into a dictionary shown above?

```
my %genericHash;
for my $entry (@$myV3VersionOfData) {
  $genericHash{ $entry->{key} } = $entry->{value};
}
```

How can I achieve this? I am new to Perl, and I have tried a bunch of things but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've done it for over 10 years.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my %entries;
my @myV3VersionOfData = ("ZG","ZB","CXLDN");
foreach (@myV3VersionOfData) {
    $entries{$_}{'value'} = $_;
}

print Dumper \%entries;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go through every element, to compute a new element, then you can use the `map` function. As map, can return multiple values, you return two values for each entry. And those can be converted to a hash.

```perl
my $array   = ["ZG","ZB","CXLDN"];
my %hash    = map { $_ => { value => $_ } } @$array;
my $hashref = { map { $_ => { value => $_ } } @$array };
```

Comment: For anyone struggling to convert a decode_json into a hashref:

`use JSON::XS;my $json = qx(cat input.json); my $vals = decode_json $json;my @array = @{$vals};my $hashref = { map { $_ => { value => $_ } } @{$vals} };`
Will convert a json array into a hashref.

Answer (score 2):

You were close.  Here is one way to create a hash reference from an array reference:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

my $myV3VersionOfData = ["ZG","ZB","CXLDN"];
my $entries;
for (@{ $myV3VersionOfData }) {
    $entries->{$_} = {value => $_};
}

print Dumper($entries);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'CXLDN' => {
                       'value' => 'CXLDN'
                     },
          'ZB' => {
                    'value' => 'ZB'
                  },
          'ZG' => {
                    'value' => 'ZG'
                  }
        };
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a ton... I see where I went wrong

Answer (score -1):

We want

```perl
'ZG' => { 'value' => 'ZG' }      # Copied literally from the Question
```

But the `ZG` part is variable, so we use

```perl
$_ => { 'value' => $_ }
```

Now loop!

```perl
my %genericHash = map { $_ => { 'value' => $_ } } @$myV3VersionOfData;
```

```perl
my $entries = { map { $_ => { 'value' => $_ } } @$myV3VersionOfData };
```

It's not clear which one you want.

Of course, it could also be done using a foreach loop.

```perl
my %genericHash;
for (@$myV3VersionOfData) {
   $genericHash{$_} = { 'value' => $_ };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please study following code snippet for compliance with your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $myV3VersionOfData = ['ZG','ZB','CXLDN'];
my $hashref;

$hashref->{$_}{value} = $_ for @$myV3VersionOfData;

say Dumper($hashref);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'CXLDN' => {
                       'value' => 'CXLDN'
                     },
          'ZB' => {
                    'value' => 'ZB'
                  },
          'ZG' => {
                    'value' => 'ZG'
                  }
        };
```